# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron, testng

I have really bad issue with this error and nothing has solved it. I already used all solutions from others but its not working. The guava versin 25.0-jre is already shown under libraries

First of all its a an electron application and starting it using ChromeOptions. Although I changed nothing, the code that works in the morning today was not working in the evening. I need really help.

JDK Version: 1.8.0_221
Chrome Version: 79.03945.36

```
public void setupEnvironment() throws InterruptedException, FindFailed {
    ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ayaz\\Documents\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    opt.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\app\\app.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
}




<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>



java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;

at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.asMap(ChromeOptions.java:292)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
at Utils.TestStructure.setupEnvironment(TestStructure.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
```

**RESOLVED**

**I was using an external jar and added it to maven local repo. Than i used -clear and -install commands and problem is fixed**

Comment: I think you might need to try `opt.setBinary(new File("/path/to/chrome"));` ?

Comment: I already tried it and its not working. Im really stucked and dont now what did effect my project. I didnt change any thing and its not working...